# SLURM status string on job completion / exit

Tags: bash, slurm, exit-code

How do I get the slurm job status (e.g. COMPLETED, FAILED, TIMEOUT, ...) on job completion (within the submission script)?
I.e. I want to write to separately keep track of jobs which are timed out / failed.

Currently I work with the exit code, however jobs which TIMEOUT also get exit code 0.

Comment: exit status is 124 for timeout, you have a misconception somewhere

Comment: Hmm, why is then `TIMEOUT, ExitCode 0`, `FAILED, ExitCode 1` or `COMPLETED, ExitCode 0` in the mail when the job is 'finished'?

Comment: i don't know https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, here is how I finally do it.

To retrieve the jobid at the beginning of the job and write some information (e.g. `"${SLURM_JOB_ID} ${PWD}"`) to a summary file.

Then process this file and use something like `sacct -X -n -o State --j ${jid}` to get the job status.